# Function to insert to a string doesn't return the expected result

Tags: python, string, function

I'm writing a function to insert `\n` to a string at about every 10 characters such that it doesn't break a word. Here's the function I come up with:

```py
def stringsplit(my_string):
    str_length = len(my_string)
    str_quotient = str_length//10 
    if str_quotient <= 1: #only split string if its length is larger than 10
        ()
    else:
        for x in range(1, str_quotient+1):
            y = 10*x
            if ' ' in my_string[y-5:y+5]:
                insert_loc = my_string.find(' ', y-5, y+5) #split string by the whole word
                my_string = my_string[:insert_loc] + '\n' + my_string[insert_loc:]
                #return my_string #This won't work
            else:
                ()
        return my_string #This works
```

Then if I run:

```py
my_string = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
my_split_string = stringsplit(my_string)
my_split_string
```

it only gives:

```py
'The quick\n brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

Whereas if I just use:

```py
my_string = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
str_length = len(my_string)
str_quotient = str_length//10
if str_quotient <= 1:
    ()
else:
    for x in range(1, str_quotient+1):
        y = 10*x
        if ' ' in my_string[y-5:y+5]:
            insert_loc = my_string.find(' ', y-5, y+5)
            my_string = my_string[:insert_loc] + '\n' + my_string[insert_loc:]
        else:
            ()
```

I will have:

```py
my_string
'The quick\n brown\n fox jumps\n over the\n lazy dog'
```

Can you tell where I did wrong with the function?

EDIT: Update solution following Johnny's tip.

Comment: You `return my_string` after adding the first newline. Don't `return` until you've processed the entire string.

Comment: FYI: [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html)

Answer (score 0):

The function is returning it's answer on the first iteration. Moving the return statement outside of the for loop will make it so it returns after each iteration has been completed. Something like this would work:

```
def stringsplit(my_string):
    str_length = len(my_string)
    str_quotient = str_length//10 
    if str_quotient <= 1: #only split string if its length is larger than 10
        ()
    else:
        for x in range(1, str_quotient+1):
            y = 10*x
            if ' ' in my_string[y-5:y+5]:
                insert_loc = my_string.find(' ', y-5, y+5) #split string by the whole word
                my_string = my_string[:insert_loc] + '\n' + my_string[insert_loc:]
                #return statement removed from here!
                
            else:
                ()

        #return statement moved to here!
        return my_string
```